# Convert TCHAR to LPWSTR in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to Convert TCHAR to LPWSTR in VC++ ?

Ex: I have

```
TCHAR  achValue[16383];
```

I want assign this value to LPWSTR .
How to achieve that in VC++

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `TCHAR` in the first place? You should be using `wchar_t` if you're targeting any modern version of Windows.

Comment: I've had to copy code from/to old ANSI projects and TCHAR makes that a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TCHAR` is either `char` or `wchar`_t based on your projects Unicode/MBCS setting. If you're compiling as unicode, `achValue` can be used as a `LPWSTR`. If not, you need to use `MultiByteToWideChar` in order to convert the characters in `achValue` from the encoding you use to UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

If your project file has `UNICODE` flag defined, then you can simply do `LPWSTR p = achValue;`

Comment: No I am using MultiByte Character Set

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up a `#ifdef`'d section to handle both cases:  One for if UNICODE is defined (meaning `TCHAR` is defined as `wchar_t`) and the other for when it isn't defined (and you'll have to use `MultiByteToWideChar` to convert it).